# Wordpress TinyMCE Stripping Custom Caption Shortcode Attributes

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I've extended Wordpress' caption shortcode with a couple custom attributes in addition to caption's default: ID, align, width, and class. My new attributes work great while everything is in Text mode. However if I switch to Visual mode and then back to Text my custom attributes get stripped off the shortcode.

For instance:

```
[caption id="attachment_6" align="alignright" width="300" custom_attr="value"]<img src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/800px-Great_Wave_off_Kanagawa2-300x205.jpg" alt="Kanagawa" title="The Great Wave" width="300" height="205" class="size-medium wp-image-6" /> The Great Wave[/caption]
```

becomes:

```
[caption id="attachment_6" align="alignright" width="300"]<img class="size-medium wp-image-6" title="The Great Wave" src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/800px-Great_Wave_off_Kanagawa2-300x205.jpg" alt="Kanagawa" width="300" height="205" /> The Great Wave[/caption]
```

The attribute is removed and the classes on the image get swapped around so clearly some process is going on.

I'm inserting my custom attributes via the `media_send_to_editor` event that occurs between the media library and the editor. I've tried adding these new attributes via the `tiny_mce_before_init` event but can't find any real documentation beyond [this WIP VIP tutorial](https://vip.wordpress.com/documentation/register-additional-html-attributes-for-tinymce-and-wp-kses/) which only seems to work from standard HTML DOM elements and not WP shortcodes.

Does anyone know how Tiny MCE handles content filtering of shortcodes, especially when it comes to switching between Visual and Text modes? Is there a filter or action where I can add my custom attributes to a whitelist of what's allowed in that transition? Thanks.

Comment: Your shortcode work fine to me  and I also use this kind of shortcode but except using any HTML on it.

Comment: You don't get the `custom_attr` stripped when toggling between visual and text mode?

Comment: Yes it cause problem if toggling between them

Comment: O so it didn't work fine for you? It gets stripped.

Comment: You better use innter shortcode for display your image or html that you want set in middle of the shortcode ( For example you can see how Visual Composer Page builder plugin generate shortcodes ). and reason why it's not working see here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/211624/64458

Comment: I went with just setting up a custom shortcode and pointing it to the same logic.